# Android, screen support issue between tablet and smart phone

Tags: android, screen, tablet, smartphone

I have a project which fully designed for smart phone and now, I need to support new 7" (Samsung 7" plus) tablet (not the old 7" with Froyo 2.2 OS).

I have added following code to my manifest file:

```
<supports-screens 
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="false"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />
```

When i run the app in this tablet new icon appears in button right corner of screen and offers two options, "Stretch to fill screen" and "Zoom to fill screen".

Because I have no resources for this tablet in first option, my UI is not good while with choosing second option the UI becomes better.

Is there a way to run my application with "Zoom to fill screen" and deactivate above icon? I don't want user has ability to switch between them.

What's your suggestion?

Comment: just try set android:largeScreens="true"

Comment: Thanks Kai, as I told above I don't have resources for that. if i change it to true the UI collapses because it loads smart phone UI. Also I miss zooming feature as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future info,

I found this way which is works fine.

```
<supports-screens 
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="false"
        android:resizeable="false"
        android:anyDensity="false" />
```